# Promise.all wait for observables

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can't make the Promise.all() wait for the items.  Below are the codes that I used.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE**

```
const items = Object.keys(this.models).map(key => {
  return this.processThenCallback(key).subscribe(() => {
    this.populateItems(key);
    return this.getOtherItems(key);
  });
});
Promise.all(items).then(() => {
  // Perform important function
});
```

I used `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'` to return an Observable;

```
private processThenCallback(key) {
    return this.someService.getThings().map(data => {
        // Do something on the data
    ));
}

private populateItems(key) {
    // Perform synchronous process, nothing special
    return key;
}

private getOtherItems(key) {
    return this.otherService.getOtherItems().map(data => {
        // Do something on data
    ));
}
```

Comment: I think the answer provided by CertainPerformance does not apply to my question.

Comment: It does. You need to change `processThenCallback` so that it returns a promise. That probably also means that you should remove the `callback` parameter and change `getOtherItems` into a promise-returning function as well.

Comment: But i need `populateItems` and `getOtherItems` to run only after `processThenCallback`.  I'm not really good in promises cannot even think of how to do it.

Comment: The duplicate explains how to create a promise that resolves when a callback happens. Please try to write versions of `process` and `getOtherItems` that do this. [Edit] your question to include the attempt. We'll see how to combine them in the `Promise.all` later.

Comment: Ok, i'll try it now.

Comment: I updated the functions to return an Observable.

Comment: Updated again the top-most code

Comment: You need to create promises, not observables, for `Promise.all` to work. Also, that `subscribe` in the top code should be replaced as well - either with `flatMap` (when working with observables) or with `then` (when already having promises).

Comment: By the way, the services are actually http service from angular that returns an Observable, that's why I use Observable

Comment: Try using `toPromise().then` instead of `pipe`

Comment: didn't work.  still the function inside the method `getOtherItems()` didn't run

Comment: Did you call `toPromise()` on that as well?

Comment: Actually that toPromise is showing errors in my terminal while compiling

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to show what you've tried? Also, *what* errors is it showing?

Comment: It works now.  I just change to `getOtherItems().toPromise()` together with `return this.processThenCallback(key).toPromise().then`... thank you so much, you've been a great help!!!